# Adding an image to a button in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to add an image to a button in my silverlight 3 application but cannot get the image to appear. I added a folder, named \images, to my Silverlight application folder and an using a relative path in the Source attribute of the Image. What am I doing wrong?

```
<Button Width="200"
        Height="200">
     <Image Source="images\document.png"></Image>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out what is going on is to add an [event handler for the ImageFailed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.imagefailed(VS.95).aspx) to see what URL it is trying to use.

You should probably try using forward slashes instead of back slashes, but I'm not sure if that is the real issue.